# i cannot retrieve the current record id in lightning experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, record

I trying to do some processing for contracts, for that, i created a custom button on the contract that call a visualforce page. I am using ligntining experience and thus i created an application to retrieve only the contracts with specific criterias, hence, i need to get the ID of the contract from which the button is clicked.

the problem is that i can not retrieve this ID, i tried the `implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId"`
thing but even that does not work, i get always `null value` (iam using system.debug() in the apex controller to check the value)

here is my code:

Visualforce page that holds the app:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contract">
 <apex:includeLightning />

 <div style="width:30%;height:100px;" id="FlipcardContainer" />

 <script>
 $Lightning.use("c:LightningOutContainerApp", function() {
 $Lightning.createComponent("c:FlipCard",
 {},
 "FlipcardContainer",
 function(cmp) {
 console.log('Component created, do something cool here');
 });
 });
 </script>
</apex:page>
```

the FlipCard component

```
<aura:component controller="contractCollectorController" access="global"   implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="contracts" type="Contract[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="theContract" 
        type="Lead" 
        default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contract',
                   'Status': '',
                   'ContractTerm': ''
                 }"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
   <!-- <form>
        <ui:inputText value="{!v.theContract.Status}" label="Company" class="input"/>
        <ui:inputText value="{!v.theContract.ContractTerm}" label="First" class="input"/>
       <ui:button label="Save" press="{!c.clickCreateContract}"/>
    </form>-->
    <ui:outputText class="form-control" aura:id="recid" value="{!v.recordId}" />
    <c:contractList contracts="{!v.contracts}"/>
</aura:component>
```

the controller :

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {

    // Create the action

    var action = component.get("c.getContracts");

        action.setParams({
        "accountId": component.get("v.recordId") /* here it sends a null value*/
    });

    // Add callback behavior for when response is received
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.contracts", response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else {
            console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
        }
    });

    // Send action off to be executed
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

the apex controller code :

```
   @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contract> getContracts(Id accountId) {
        system.debug(accountId);
        // recuperer le contract en cours
        List<Contract> Contrat = [select Id, Status,Group__c from Contract where Id =: accountId];

        return [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name, Status, ContractTerm 
                FROM Contract where Group__c =: Contrat.get(0).group__c];
    }
```

Comment: Hi. I've removed my answer as it obviously didn't solve the problem like I thought it would! The only thing I can think now is that force:hasRecordId doesn't work when the component is rendered via Lightning Out (on visualforce). Have you/can you try putting your component direct on a record page using the Lightning App Builder in LEX and checking if it works there? If so, I would deduce it's LightningOut... if not, we will need to dig deeper!

Comment: actually what i want to do is to call the Lightning app from a button, i did not find any other way except by creating a visualforce page to hold the app, all what i want is to click on a button in the record layout for the app to be launched, it is extremely easy to do that in the classic with visualforce pages, but here i am forced to use Lightning

Comment: i will try what you have said, i will keep you updated

Comment: If you use the lightning app builder to make a new record detail page for your object you can add a new tab (next to "Details", "Related" ... ) and then house your lightning component under there, it's kinda like having a button... (but that might be a whole different question) good luck!

Comment: Yes, it works the way you said, i think that the problem is the the way your Lightning Component is called from the page

Comment: @Simon Lawrence can you please elaborate more about this method to simulate a button on the layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have quotes around `"accountId"`. Take them out and your code should work. Code sample below.

```
var action = component.get("c.getContracts");

action.setParams({
    accountId: component.get("v.recordId") /* here it sends a null value*/
});
```

Another thing that could be causing the problem is the lack of parameters when you create the component

```
$Lightning.createComponent("c:FlipCard",
 {recordId : '{!Contract.id}'},
 "FlipcardContainer",
 function(cmp) {
 console.log('Component created, do something cool here');
 });
```

You have the 2nd parameter above empty, which means no parameters are passed to the component when you create it. My updated code above is indeed passing a parameter.

Comment: If the above doesn't work (and I don't know why it shouldn't), you should add a `{!v.recordId}` markup in your component, to ensure that the ID you want is actually being passed to the component. If that markup is not null, then your problem is in the Lightning Component. If it is null, then the issue is in the way your Lightning Component is called from VF.

Comment: I took off the quotes and still it does not work, i tried what @Simon Lawrence suggested by adding the component using the app builder and it works so, i think that the problem is the the way your Lightning Component is called from the page

Comment: Did you add the markup I suggested?

Comment: Yes, the value is null

Comment: Look at my updated answer...

Comment: Woot! If it worked for you, please feel free to vote and mark as accepted so others can benefit from the answer.

Comment: the quote marks don't make any difference to passing the params to the Apex method. By adding recordId to the LightningOut construct though, you are effectively bypassing the point of the force.hasRecordId interface - which is fine, if you will always be loading this component using the visualforce/lightningOut library using that markup - but if you are going to put this component anywhere else and depend on force:hasRecordId, we unfortunately haven't solved the problem with that...

Comment: @SimonLawrence Your second point is not correct. If you place the component in a Lightning page, the `recordId` property will be filled out properly by the system. The OP's problem is that, by putting in the VF page, there no automatic population of the property.

Comment: I'm 50/50 on that without trying it. If you define your own aura:attribute called recordId (not of type String) you will break force:hasRecordId - see here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_record_home.htm "You don’t need to add a recordId attribute to a component yourself if it implements force:hasRecordId. If you do add it, don’t change the access level or type of the attribute or the component will cause a runtime error." - you could change the type to be String.. but that starts to get a bit messy for my liking!

Comment: I am 100% on it. I've been using that pattern for a while. I have a component that can either be standalone or a child of another component. When I create it as a child, I pass "recordId" as a parameter. If not, the interface takes care of it. It is `String`, not `Id`, but that's a quick and easy change for the OP.